# What is the ideal way of communicating within the same level sibling directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I have a code segment in a controller which define directives within a ng-repeat statement.

```
    <div class="Value" ng-repeat="value in valueList">
       <my-directive inner-value="value"></my-directive>
   </div>
```

Here I want to communicate between the directives (e.g. - the button in the 2nd directive to be appeared when click on the button of the 1st directive)

What would be the ideal way of communicating between the same level directives through the controller

Comment: would it be possible to generalize this question for oop? I think question and answer are both OO Concept focussed and not only for angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I know of :

### Events

- Child Components trigger events .
- Parent receives them and decide what to do

### Service

- All components inject the service
- Service has a subject which all components listen to
- When button is clicked any component can call the service to update
- For each update each component is aware of the change

### Which I prefer ?

*Service based*

### Why ?

- Disadvantages of Events

  - Having events complicates the flow, all the components are fixed in their places. We also need to worry about sharing data between them . Multiple inputs , their state etc., big mess.
  - If there are lot of changes its difficult to track
  - Logic resides in Component, difficult to test and maintain . I love dummy components
- Advantages of Service

  - All logic resides in service, easy to test and maintain
  - Components can move across , change their position still works great
  - Adding new components is breeze, don't need to rewrite the whole logic again
  - Utilize the power of rx programming and simplify any complex logic